# dynamic_reconfigure and catkin - is tutorial correct?

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to follow:

[this tuturial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile)

the catkin version but following these instructions give:

```
tompe@heyer:~/lrs_ws/src/lrs_firefly_usb$ cfg/ffcam.cfg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfg/ffcam.cfg", line 10, in <module>
    gen = ParameterGenerator()
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamic_reconfigure/parameter_generator_catkin.py", line 234, in __init__
    self.dynconfpath = sys.argv[1]  # FIXME this is awful
IndexError: list index out of range
```

if I just try to run the script and it does not work at all in catkin (no files generated). Replacing

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
```

with

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator import *
```

works better since it at least generates the files. So is this a bug or not?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55647/dynamic_reconfigure-and-catkin---is-tutorial-correct?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-20**:
I am having problems catkinizing a dynamic_reconfigure server, too. But, in my case I only get the files generated with `parameter_generator_catkin()`.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-22**:
There is something strange going on here, and we need to get to the bottom of it.

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-07-29**:
I'm having the same problem. Removing _catkin does work via python script but does not solve the catkin_make-error.

**Comment by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) on 2014-11-11**:
Are there any updates for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generator scripts [can't be called directly](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile#dynamic_reconfigure.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile.2BAC8-catkin.Use_the_cfg_File), you'll need make sure your `CMakeLists.txt` file contains the following line:

```
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/ffcam.cfg)
```

However, `ParameterGenerator` should output a more helpful message, I filed a ticket at https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/issues/32

---

Originally posted by [esteve](https://answers.ros.org/users/4526/esteve/) with karma: 89 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1